# In the Sandbox for some reason the master-chat.js produces an error on loading

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

When I enter the [Sandbox](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/651/sandbox) with IE11 I never get passed the Loading splash screen.

The Developer Console says:

> Invalid argument. File: master-chat.js, Line: 10, Column: 398

That happens on these lines:

```
 var a = b.extend({}, e.defaults, a), h = b.map(f, function (b) {
    if (b) {
        if (b.split)
            // busgs here
            return a.base + b + a.ext;
        var d = b.src || b.href;
        if ("string" == typeof a.placeholder && b.src)
            b.src = a.placeholder;
        d && a.find && (d = d.replace(a.find,
                    a.replace));
        return d || null
    }
})
```

Notice that the other rooms work all fine.

If I manually remove the loading div I can post chat messages but I don't see any content-updates, nor mine nor from others.

This bug is confirmed by at least one other user and doesn't repro in Chrome or Firefox.

Can this be investigated?

Comment: Repro'd w/ IE11, **Tavern works fine**.

Comment: It's been six hours since this was posted, so I don't know if it's been looked at or not, but I just tried it and I'm not getting any console errors, but it is taking forever (in the literal sense) to load past the "Loading Sandbox" dialog. If I try and leave, it's giving "Unable to get property 'windowClosing' of undefined or null reference" on line 289 of that file. I, too, have IE 11. Chrome is working. *Edit:** interesting, now I'm getting the same as you. No idea why, but I got that immediately on my third try. Something's definitely strange on that one.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen The `windowClosing` thing was just a side effect of the fact that the underlying issue with the broken image interrupted the initialization of the JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somebody posted an image into the Sandbox with a pretty broken URL, and IE throws an exception even when you're just *reading* the image's URL. I've deleted the image as a quickfix and will add a workaround to prevent this from happening again.

Comment: Yep, works again. Thanks for the quick-fix and good luck with adding the workaroud. We IE11 users like it to be special ;)

Comment: @rene The workaround is being deployed right now.

Comment: Or in other words, we're free to try and break it again ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard https://twitter.com/kevinmontrose/status/572573906537713664

Comment: I don't dare to ask but can you share the url or repost it in the Sandbox?

Comment: @rene `http://about:blank//ascriptalert(hello);/scripta.jpg`